# React setState Array Hook doesn't re-render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I am trying to create Table collapse and expand feature in React similar as pivot table in Excel. Here is my javascript code.

```js
const data = {
  'T-Shirt Minion': {
    'total': 571,
    'var': {
      'Lengan Panjang': {
        'total': 431,
        'colour': {
          'Merah': {
            'total': 431,
            'size': {
              'XL': 231,
              'S': 100,
              'M': 100
            }
          }
        }
      },
      'Lengan Pendek': {
        'total': 140,
        'colour': {
          'Merah': {
            'total': 140,
            'size': {
              'L': 140
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

function MyApp() {
  const [dataShow, setDataShow] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
      setDataShow((prev) => [...prev, {
        'name': Object.keys(data)[i],
        'total': data[Object.keys(data)[i]]['total']
      }]);
    }

  }, []);

  const handleNameClick = (idx, name) => {
    if (dataShow[idx].var) {
      let temp = dataShow;
      delete temp[idx].var;

      setDataShow(temp);
    } else {
      const data_temp = data[name]['var']

      let i = 0;

      let temp = dataShow;
      temp[idx]['var'] = [];

      for (let value in data_temp) {
        temp[idx]['var'][i] = {
          'name': value,
          'total': data_temp[value]['total']
        };

        i += 1;
      }

      setDataShow(temp);
    }
  };

  return ( 
  <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> </th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Variant</th>
                            <th>Colour</th>
                            <th>Size</th>
                            <th>Stock</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {dataShow.map((row, index) => (
                        <React.Fragment key={`${index}${row.name}`}>
                            <tr>
                                <td style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} 
                                    onClick={() => handleNameClick(index, row.name)}> + </td>
                                <td colSpan={4} >{row.name}</td>
                                <td>{row.total}</td>
                            </tr>
                            {row.var ? row.var.map((var_idx, var_value) => (
                                <React.Fragment key={`${var_idx}${var_value.name}`}>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}> + </td>
                                        <td> </td>
                                        <td colSpan={3}>{var_value.name}</td>
                                        <td>{var_value['total']}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </React.Fragment>
                            )) : null }
                        </React.Fragment>
                      ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  MyApp / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Basically I have implement setState when the + button is clicked, then the table data will be updated. If table data is updated, I expect that the table will be reloaded with new row child. But the problem there is no updated in the table. Is there something wrong with my code ?

Comment: The problem is this: `let temp = dataShow;` You need `let temp = [...dataShow];` instead so an actual copy is created, otherwise you're mutating state directly and React can't detect the change.

Comment: @ChrisG - And then they *also* need to copy the object being modified by the `delete` operation (in the `if` branch near the top).

Comment: All of the code in `handleNameClick` should be inside the `setDataShow` callback using the version of `dataShow` that's passed to the callback, because you're using existing state (`dataShow`) to update state, including making decisions based on what's in `dataShow`. (With a click handler you're usually okay, `dataShow` is unlikely to be stale -- but **only** unlikely, not guaranteed, so no need to risk it.)

Comment: Thank you @ChrisG, changing from let temp = dataShow; to let temp = [...dataShow]; works for me. May I know why is this happening ?

Comment: When you call a state setter, React compares the passed object with the previous state. When you do `let temp = dataShow;` then both `temp` and `dataShow` are referencing the same object in memory, which means when React does `if (newState === oldState)` it's a match. So from React's point of view nothing was changed, and thus nothing needs to be re-rendered. This is a core concept and explained in the tutorial: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#why-immutability-is-important

Comment: @ChrisG very well noted, thank you so much for enlightening me.